# google custom search site specific search in V1 code

Tags: google-custom-search

Can someone help me with how to implement a site specific search in google custom search **version 1** code?  Ex.  search only 
http://www.example.net/somesite/somesubsite/

For version 2 code, I can use the ***as_sitesearch*** parameter.  But I need more control over the style of the search form, so I must use V1. I'm unclear how to implement this with V1.

Also, I cannot find documentation on the scripting that's incorporated into v1, if someone knows where that might be hiding, I would appreciate it.  I have scoured https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/ and I must be overlooking it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Google custom search V1 data rendering docs, located here https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/rendering